# table expanding after call data from database "PHP"

Tags: php, database

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = '/////////';
    $dbpass = '////////';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die                      ('Error connecting to mysql');

    $dbname = '///////';
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conn);  
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM 3orod";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $i= 0;
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html dir="rtl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="ar-sa" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
    <title>آخر العروض</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
      width: 99%;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      background-color: gray;
      color: #505050;
    }

    .website {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border:1px solid #000000;
      border-radius: 10px;
      min-width:860px;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000000;
      max-height: 99%;
      min-height: 600;
      height: 99%;
    }

    .header {
    background-color: #E6F3DB;
    font-size:small;
    font-style:oblique;

    }

    .header2 {
    background-color: #E6F3DB;
    font-size:small;
    font-style:oblique;

    }


    .row {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size:small;
    font-style:oblique;
    }


    table {
    border:1px solid #000000;
    max-width:99%;
    }
    td {
    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="website">
    <table width="100%" border="1">
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

    if ($i == 0){
    echo "<tr>".
            "<td  class='header'>   {$row['A']}</td>".
            "<td width='3%' class='header'> {$row['B']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['C']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['D']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['E']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['F']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['G']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['H']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header2'> {$row['I']}</td>".
             "<td width='1px' class='header'>   {$row['J']}</td>".
             "<td width='1px' class='header'>   {$row['K']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['L']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['M']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['N']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['O']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['P']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['Q']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['R']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['S']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['T']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['U']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['V']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['W']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['X']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['Y']}</td>".
             "<td  class='header'>  {$row['Z']}</td>".
             "</tr>"     ;
             $i=1;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<tr>".
            "<td  class='row'>  {$row['A']}</td>".
            "<td width='3%' class='row'>    {$row['B']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['C']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['D']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['E']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['F']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['G']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['H']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row2'>    {$row['I']}</td>".
             "<td width='1px' class='row'>  {$row['J']}</td>".
             "<td width='1px' class='row'>  {$row['K']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['L']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['M']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['N']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['O']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['P']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['Q']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['R']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['S']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['T']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['U']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['V']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['W']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['X']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['Y']}</td>".
             "<td  class='row'> {$row['Z']}</td>".
             "</tr>"     ;
    } 
    }
    mysql_close();
    ?>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

if you see the results you can see that the cells expanding with no reason 
http://www.almousaakar.com/test/3orod/admin/

my regards

Comment: Implement paging of the results. `LIMIT` is your friend. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cells aren't expanding for no reason, they're expanding to fit the cell contents. Take a look at [automatic table layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#auto-table-layout). Also, the HTML4 spec says about [table cell width](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.4):

> If column widths prove to be too narrow for the contents of a particular table cell, user agents may choose to reflow the table.

It's bad form both to link to an enormous page as a sample and to link to an enormous page without warning. Some browsers might misbehave, and people won't appreciate you crashing their browser. [Samples](http://sscce.org/) (both pages and code) should be concise and complete. Remove anything extraneous, both from sample code and by reducing the results displayed.

### Off-Topic

For header cells, use [`<th>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6), not `<td>` with a class. Keep it [semantic](http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/5-site-structure/2-semantic-markup.html).

If you find yourself repeating code, you should be using a function or a loop.

The mysql extension is on its way to deprecation. Use PDO or mysqli, both of which support prepared statements.

Hopefully, you're not putting the database credentials in the main script as you do in the sample. Sensitive information should be kept in a single location, where it's easier to secure. Also, the more you repeat something, the greater chance for a typo. [Don't repeat yourself](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself).

Names should be descriptive; single letter column (or variable or ...) names aren't. They've even been part of a [daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Trust_me,_It_0x27_s_Easier_This_Way.aspx). Hopefully, this is just in the sample code and the production code (and database) has more descriptive names.

Style sheets are preferred over the `width` attribute for setting table cell width, as a consequence of separation of structure from presentation. You can give cells a class to target in selectors; when they have broader browser support, you can use [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) or [`:nth-of-type()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo) pseudo-classes in selectors (e.g. `tr > nth-child(2)`, `th:nth-of-type(2), td:nth-of-type(2)`) rather than classes. From the same section of the HTML4 spec that was previously linked to:

> Note. Although the width attribute on the TABLE element is not deprecated, authors are encouraged to use style sheets to specify table widths.

Here's an example that incorporates changes for some of these issues. First, 'localdb.php', a class that handles DB connection creation and lets you isolate credentials somewhere (though where isn't shown). Note that it still has problems (such as data access and presentation are too closely coupled).

```
<?php
class LocalDB {
    static function connect($dbName=null) {
        if ($dbName) {
            $dbName = ";dbname=$dbName";
        }
        try {
            $db = PDO("mysql:hostname=localhost$dbName", 
                      self::user(), self::password(), 
                      array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            # can cause problems in some versions of PHP 5.2
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, False);
            return $db;
        } catch (PDOException $exc) {
            # remove call to PDO's constructor from trace, which will include
            # database credentials
            throw new PDOException($exc->getMessage(), $exc->getCode());
        }
    }
    static private user() {...}
    static private password() {...}
}
```

Next, the main script (without the [embedded style sheet](http://cssfreakie.blogspot.com/2011/03/dont-use-inline-style.html), since that doesn't matter in the example and should, in any case, be placed in an external style sheet):

```
<?php
include_once('path/to/localdb.php');
$db = LocalDB::connect(...);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="rtl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="ar-sa" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
    <title>آخر العروض</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="website">
    <?php
    try {
        $result = $db->query(...);
        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        ?>
        <table>
          <?php $header = $result->fetch(); ?>
          <tr>
            <?php foreach ($header as $field => $value) { ?>
              <th class="<?php echo $field ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></th>
            <?php } ?>
          </tr>
          <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
              <?php foreach ($row as $field => $value ?>
                <td class="<?php echo $field ?>"><?php echo $value ?></td>
              <?php } ?>
            </tr>
          <?php } ?>
        </table>
      <?php } catch (PDOException $exc) { ?>
          <p>There was an internal error when fetching the data. It's been logged, and we'll look into it.</p>
          <?php 
          // log exception
          ...
      } ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your instructions i'm newbie and learning stuff and this is my first time to ask for help, i dont know the rules of posting things, another question: if i use limit how can i make pages with numbers to go through results ? thank you

Comment: New questions (as opposed to requests for clarifications) should be posted as new questions, rather than in comments. In part this is because SO is a Q&A site, rather than a forum; as a result, trying to ask new questions in a comment won't work very well. However, that question's been asked many times before on SO, so you shouldn't post a new question. Instead, try searching for existing ones.

Comment: i'm afraid i cant get it to work,but thank you i learned new stuff